# rotate an image multiple times on click with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, rotation

I am trying to rotate an image using jquery that will rotate on multiple mouse clicks. Using the [jquery-rotate](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-rotate/) plugin, the following code only rotates the image once (transforming to a canvas in firefox) and will no longer rotate on further clicks.

```
$(".drag-and-rotatable img").click(function() {
    $(this).rotate(45);
});
```

I'm open to using other JavaScript libraries.

Comment: I think you should remove raphael and raphael-js tags. It could confuse people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say `rotate(45)`, you are rotating the image 45 degrees? (make sure it's not radians, I don't use the plugin) from the original rotation, so if you want to keep rotating you have to keep adding or subtracting degrees:

```
$(function() {                                    // doc ready
    var rotation = 0;                             // variable to do rotation with
    $(".drag-and-rotatable img").click(function() {
        rotation = (rotation + 45) % 360; // the mod 360 probably isn't needed
        $(this).rotate(rotation);
    });
});
```

Comment: there are 360 degrees, not 365 ;)

Comment: @WoLpH - I was obviously thinking of the rarely used day angle ;) .... whoops, thanks.